# Downgrade composer 2.x > 1.x in ddev not working

Tags: docker, composer-php, ddev

I am using ddev with DDEV version v1.21.3
on WSL2 and changed the composer version in the config.yml to 1
But even after deleting the docker images my project always starts with this composer version:
Composer version 2.4.3 2022-10-14 16:56:41

I did run `ddev config --composer-version=1 && ddev start` like the ddev docs say, but no change.
**Any idea how to fix that?**

Composer 1.x works fine on my other ddev setups with older ddev versions. But not on this fresh installed dev machine.

**Additional Info from later Tests (moved from Comments)**
I just tried it with a completely empty project. Changed the value in config.yml right before ddev restart.
Console output:

```
Your project can be reached at https://testddev.ddev.site https://127.0.0.1:49249
drupal@Wks:~/testddev$ ddev exec composer --version
Composer version 2.4.3 2022-10-14 16:56:41 
drupal@WksHzdWiF6337:~/testddev$ ddev version
ITEM             VALUE
DDEV version     v1.21.3
```

Got it working with downgrading ddev to 1.17.0 but not with the latest ddev version or someting like 1.19

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this. After doing what you did you should see `composer_version: 1` in your .ddev/config.yaml. And `ddev exec composer --version` should show 1.10.26 or something like that. Is it possible that your project is installing a different composer during startup?

Comment: Well not really, as we are still bound to composer 1. Changed `composer_version: "1"` to `composer_version: 1` in config.yaml but no difference when doing a ddev restart. which composer returns /usr/local/bin/composer when run in container. I even deleted every generated config files and reconfigured the project, purged and rmi-ed images. Still the same. Will try with a blank project.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Yes, I think with a plain vanilla project you'll find it  has composer 1. `mkdir junk && cd junk && ddev config --composer-version=1 && ddev start && ddev exec composer --version`.  I get `Composer version 1.10.26 2022-04-13 16:39:56`

Comment: @rfay: Does ddev has support for Composer 2.2 release channel? That's the LTS version and normally Composer 1 users can benefit (and should have no blockers) to upgrade to 2.2 even if stuck on older PHP versions (network operation and dependency resolution is also much better).

Comment: See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/configuration/config_yaml/#composer_version and use `ddev config --composer-version=2.2`